# Saving text content from image file as image file in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to save a file contents as an image file and stuck. In the code below, original.png is a valid PNG file.

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\original.png");
```

What I've been trying is simply to save the `fileContent` as C:\temp\resaved.png.

Attempted various ways, including using Image object, writing to FileStream and save, etc. but none worked.Any tips would be appreciated!

The original file actually comes from network, but the content is the same as loading with `File.ReadAllText`.

Comment: You can't use `string` for this as it can't hold zero-value bytes.

Comment: Use File.ReadAll*Bytes* and its corollary , WriteAllBytes.. Or better, just use File.Copy if you don't need the bytes in memory for any reason

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'm not sure that's true..

Comment: @CaiusJard, thanks for the comments. The string comes from the network, and I cannot do File.WriteAllBytes. File.ReadAllText above is just to explain the problem.

Comment: *I cannot do File.WriteAllBytes* - why not?

Comment: You can't use text to represent binary data, and an image file is 100% binary data. You have to use binary, which would mean bytes, which means you use `ReadAllBytes` and `WriteAllBytes`, as @CaiusJard has already said. *I cannot do File.WriteAllBytes` is nonsense; if you can do `WriteAllText`, you can use `WriteAllBytes`.

Comment: @CaiusJard: You cannot use a string to hold binary data, because a null terminator (ASCII 0) is a string terminator. Also, reading binary data into a string and writing it back out will add CRLF characters or discard content, which corrupts the contents. Use bytes for binary data, and strings for characters.

Comment: Caius and Ken, thanks!  I tried below but no luck. Do you see anything obviously wrong?
 File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\resaved.png", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent));

Comment: @Ken *because a null terminator (ASCII 0) is a string terminator* that may be true in some windows contexts, but it isn't true in .net

Comment: *Do you see anything obviously wrong?* - er, yeah. You're mangling a PNG through interpretation as ASCII. It's toast

Comment: @CaiusJard: I'm pretty sure it is; if it wasn't, why would both `ReadAllText` and `ReadAllBytes` be necessary at all?

Comment: One returns a string to a specified encoding, the other returns bytes (which have no encoding) but the point is that putting a \0 in an .net string does not cause it to stop at that point. https://dotnetfiddle.net/dqiu9G (but if you did e.g. MessageBox.Show("Hello\0world") in a winforms app then it *would* stop after hello, but tha'ts windows' fault, not ,nets's)

Comment: @CaiusJard, so, if I got fileContent  as string, there is no way to re-save as png?

Comment: Er, it really depends on how the file is represented - is it a string because it's base64, for example.. ? Show us the code that reads it "from the network" - whatever that means.

Comment: The file is a plain PNG file, and the fileContents is the same as the one from File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\original.png").

Comment: So you're telling me it looks like this in the debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnest.png

Comment: (Hah. That's the coolest random imgur filename i've ever managed to make)

Comment: @CaiusJard, your comments around "Show us the code that reads it "from the network"", I reviewed and realized that I should have obtained the image content as binary in the first place. It comes from HTTP POST and I was doing ReadAsStringAsync... Apology and thanks for the help!

Comment: No, you're straw-manning. .net has no problem at all holding \0 in a string, working with it, working beyond it etc.. If, however, you try to put that string into a windows control such as a label, then everything after the first \0 is not displayed. It's not .net's fault, it's windows' fault. 500-ISE said "strings can't hold \0" - that's not true. You came in reiterating it, but it still didn't make it true. I've no qualms with your asserting that reading a PNG into a string shafts it up, but the \0 doesn't terminate it - see my posted screenshot

Comment: *I was doing ReadAsStringAsync* - yep, definitely recommend switching to ReadAsByteArray or ReadAsStream.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Using this code below I was able to accomplish creating a new image from a different one obtained on a network connection:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = Task.Run(() => download());
            x.Wait();
            byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\image35.png");
            Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\image36.png", fileContent);
        }
        static Task download()
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/477-4772195_monster-monstersinc-mike-wazowski-mikewazowski-mike-wazowski-meme.png";
                client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\image35.png");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't be sure of the exact purpose of this as you can duplicate the image using `DownloadFile` if it is on a network, but this code obtains the original image and then duplicates it to the indicated file name. `Task.Run()` was used to ensure we are synchronized and the file is fully obtained before attempting to duplicate it.

We cannot use `ReadAllText` so easily because the encoding of a string and the encoding of the image will be different.

Comment: `Main` can be `async` and you need to `await DownloadFileTaskAsync()`. `Task.Run()` is not required -- With an `async` method that doesn't `await` anything, don't you have some kind of warning there? You should not ignore it.

Comment: the warning you get there will tell you that you either must await inside of the async task or await the task itself. Running the task with `Task.Run()` and then hard `.Wait()` (a blocking, synchronized await call) resolves the actual issue flagged by intellisense even if intellisense cannot detect this.

Comment: You are right though, there are better ways to go about it, but I am not actually trying to write the code for him more than I am showing a proof of concept that using byte arrays work because in the comments he seemed to have a serious issue with this method.

Comment: Since you mentioned, there's no reason to run a Task to then wait for it right after. Everything here is synchronous, you can simply call the synchronous `DownloadFile()` and be done with it.

Comment: The reason I went that direction is because my console app I tested it with was trying to move on the moment the file started downloading rather than the moment it finished downloading, so it would present exceptions for the file being in use when attempting to read it into a byte array. Maybe I missed something more obvious there! It happens to the best of us and I am not among the best for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the post, it looks like it's impossible to save a string as PNG once it's loaded with File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\original.png") (or ReadAsString, which I was doing in the real scenario). I should have used ReadAsByteArray or ReadAsStream against `HttpResponseMessage.Content`.Thanks @CaiusJard.

Comment: You can remove the *very difficult* thing. It's simply nonsensical.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with Jimi.